# Error in making release apk or run the app in release mode

Tags: flutter, dart, apk

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':thumbnails:verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
> com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\asus.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\fdd1d924d9d4aeba2785fceb0b790aec\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

```
 C:\Users\asus\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\fdd1d924d9d4aeba2785fceb0b790aec\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      46.0s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is
about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the "thumbnails" package which you are using was not upgraded to AndroidX, while others are.

I recommend following this answer. This is taken from the issues page of this package.
https://github.com/asapJ/Flutter_Thumbnails/issues/8

Comment: are you using the thumbnails package or any packages that depend on thumbnails?

Comment: Possible solution it seems, give this a try. 

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32595#issuecomment-491639786